# Auto triggering of google PlaceAutocompleteFragment

Tags: android, google-maps, autocompletetextview

```
<fragment
     android:id="@+id/place_autocomplete_fragment"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:name="com.google.android.gms.location.places.ui.PlaceAutocompleteFragment"/>
```

I am reading the fragment by

PlaceAutoCompleteFragment fromCity = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.source);

View destinationClearView = fromPlace.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_clear_button);

But destinationClearView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) is not working, How to acheive that?

Comment: Try to more elaborate.

Comment: PlaceAutoCompleteFragment fromCity = (PlaceAutocompleteFragment)getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.source);
        fromCity.setHint(getString(R.string.your_location));
        fromCity.setOnPlaceSelectedListener(new PlaceSelectionListener() {
            Override
            public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
               //Do something with place
            }

            Override
            public void onError(Status status) {
                //Do something on error
            }
        });
     
Here I want to click on that widget programatically

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný  and How can I get callback when user clears the place by clicking on clear icon

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný I am accessing clear view by
destinationClearView = destinationWidget.getView().findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_clear_button);
 
And I added onclick listener to as I have to do some functionality, But it's not excecuting methods in parent fragment that is clearing the text, hiding the clearbutton

How can I achieve that?

Comment: Write(edit) it to question, it will go throw sys one again. You will get better answers. :)

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný can I change the visibility of that edittext, clear view

Comment: @PřemyslŠťastný I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

It's not good way, but it's work.

```
View close = viewOfFragment.findViewById(R.id.place_autocomplete_clear_button);
ViewsUtils.setVisible(false, close);
lp = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) close.getLayoutParams();
lp.height = 1;
lp.width = 1;
close.requestLayout();
```